# Computing $k$ eigenvectors of an hermitian matrix that have the greatest scalar product with a fixed vector $w$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, hermitian-matrices

Let $A$ be an Hermitian $n \times n$ matrix and $w$ be a fixed vector $\in \mathbb{R}^n$ of norm one, i.e. $\|w\| = 1$.
Is there a way to find the set of eigenvectors of $A$ that have the greatest scalar product with $w$ among all eigenvectors of $A$?

I.e. is there an iterative method to solve the following problem
$$ \text{argmax}_{Q, \lambda} \ \ \|Qw\|^2 \text{ s.t. } QA = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} \lambda_1 & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \lambda_k \end{array}\right) Q \text{ and } QQ^T = I$$
where $Q$ is a $k \times n$ matrix that collects $k$ eigenvectors, one per row.

Comment: $Q$ is orthogonal, so $\|Qw\| = \|w\| = 1$. So, your problem formulation is trivial. Moreover, it doesn't match with the problem formulation that you describe in the text before.

Comment: @amsmath $Q$ is not square! so $QQ^T = I$ but $Q^TQ \neq I$, and $\|Qw\|^2 = \sum_i \left< v_i, w \right>^2$ if we call $v_i$ the rows of Q.

Comment: Note that the $v_i$ constitute a orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$, so $\sum_{i\in I}\langle v_i,w\rangle^2\le\|w\|^2=1$ for all subsets $I$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Hence, the maximum is reached when you consider all eigenvectors: $\sum_{i=1}^n\langle v_i,w\rangle^2 = \|w\|^2=1$. If $w$ happens to be orthogonal to some of the $v_i$, then also fewer eigenvectors can be chosen.

Comment: @amsmath But I want to find the $k$ greatest eigenvectors, i.e. I only consider $k$ terms in the sum and I want to find the eigenvectors that maximize it

Comment: "Let $A$ be an Hermitian $n \times n$ matrix and $w$ be fixed unitary vector $\in \mathbb{R}^n$."  What does this mean?  There's no such thing as a unitary vector and the use of Hermitian and a ground field of reals is confusing as well.

Comment: @user8675309 What I meant was for $w$ to be of norm one, i.e. $\|w\| = 1$, I've corrected this in the question. Concerning the other part, $A$ is Hermitian, and $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for my problem. If the problem can be solved also for complex $w$ then the better, but I restricted it to be a real vector in case some trick is available in this case and not in the case of complex vectors.

Comment: I think you mean the field is reals so A is in fact real symmetric.  Your identity $QQ^T=I$ isn't true if $A$ is complex Hermitian.